# Octave mod function and integer

Tags: matlab, octave, modulo

I have a problem when I call the `mod` function. I have a variable M which is a two dimensional vector. When I print `M`, I see `M = [350,240.00]`.

Here is the problem : when I type `mod(M(1),10)`, I obtain `0` which is fine but I get `10` when I type `mod(M(2),10)`.

I don't know if anyone has ever encounter this kind of problem or has an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of the [mod](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Utility-Functions.html) function says that it "[...]is written such that the correct modulus is returned for integer types."

Therefore you should cast the value to an integer before applying `mod`, for example:

```
>> M = int64(M)
```

now

```
>> mod(M(2),10)
```

will give you correct answer, 0.

Comment: The problem is that M is computed and is not always an integer. I need to check if its coordinates are both a multiple of 10 and that is the test I have been chosing until now but if you have another idea ... Thanks.

Comment: The 'fmod' or 'rem' function return the same "incorrect" value 10. Of course if I type M = [350,240.00] in command line, I get 0  but not during my program.

Comment: Did you cast to integer with int64?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check if a floating point number is a multiple of `10` then you need to choose a precision to work with. For example is `240.000000000000000000000000000000000001` a multiple of `10`? It probably should be for your case. You need to be careful because your computer can't always exactly represent for floating point number in it's decimal format because internally it is stored in binary. For example `0.1` looks pretty precise in decimal, if I do something like `0:0.1:100` then you'd expect a few numbers in that series to be perfectly divisible by `10`. However `0.1` in binary is `0.0001100110011001100...` which is requires at all and it will at some tiny precision get truncated by your computer. Now when you start adding them all up those tiny truncation errors compound and can result in you storing something like `10.00000000000000000008989883` instead of a perfect 10. So that's why you need to choose a minimum precision you're will to work with and ignore any errors below that.

I suggest you round off to some precision and then check the multiple from there e.g.

```
p = 1e8 %//Check to 8 decimal points
mod(floor(M(2)*p), 10*p)
```